# jQuery basic form validation if or

Tags: jquery, if-statement, validation

this is not working and i cant really see anything wrong with it, looks straightforward enough:

```
            $("#formLogin").submit(function(){
                var username = $("#username").val();
                var password = $("#password").val();
                if (username == ' ' || password == ' '){
                    return false;
                }
                else return true;
            });
```

EDIT:

Its still submitting the form even if the fields are empty

Comment: What is not working? the if statement? or getting the username and password value?

You are comapring the username and password with and single space.. try username == ''

Comment: *Not working* is not an error description. Your `if` can be written shorter as `return username !== '' && password !== '';` (assuming you want to compare against empty values).

Comment: what values are you getting if you alert(username); and alert(password);  Is the if statement hitting the 'return false' section?

Comment: I get two alerts of no characters

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you trying to detect blank usernames and passwords?

```
  $("#formLogin").submit(function(){
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            if (jquery.trim(username) == '' || jquery.trim(password) == ''){
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        });
```

[jquery.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) removes leading and trailing spaces, so just in case the user types a number of space characters it will be detected.

Comment: thanks for this. But i'm not sure why it still isn't working. It's still submitting even if i don't fill in the fields!?

Comment: no need to use == '', if(jQuery.trim(value)) should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, why not simply use the jQuery Validation Plugin - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

VALIDATE FORMS LIKE YOU'VE NEVER BEEN VALIDATING BEFORE! (According to the site)

Answer (score 0):

In the html add this
     `<input type="submit" value="SomeButton" onclick="return submitClicked();" />`

in the js do this

```
function submitClicked() {
    if ($("#passwordInput").val() == '')
    {
        alert('missing password field');
        return false;
    }
```